# pyodbc not returning SQL results and not throwing an error

Tags: python, sql-server, pyodbc

Im trying to run some simple test code on our SQL servers, but no results are returning and there isn't an error being thrown.

Ive tried having the connect() with all the information on one line and also having each line in '' but nothing has made a difference so far. I also tried to close the connection after at the end of test() and that also didnt work.

```
from pyodbc import *

conn = connect(
    Driver='{SQL Server}',
    Server='servername',
    Database='databasename',
    Trusted_connection='yes'
)


def test():
    cursor = conn.cursor()
    cursor.execute('SELECT TOP 100 * FROM TABLENAME')
    cursor.fetchall()

    for row in cursor:
        print(row)
    conn.close()

test()
```

Earlier i ran this code twice and revived proper results. Now i dont pull results nor is there an error code explaining why.

Comment: at a guess `fetchall()` is consuming all results which means there's nothing left for the `for` loop to iterate over.  i.e. you need to remove the `cursor.fetchall()` line

Comment: that worked. Thank you!!